# SPARQL anonymous variable name, for a variable whose value I don't care about

Tags: sparql, anonymous, blank-nodes

Does SPARQL have "*don't care*" variables?

Let's say I want all items that have a [end time](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P582), but I don't care what the end time actually is:

```
?item wdt:P582 ?iWillNeverNeedThisVariable.
```

Is there a more elegant way to write this, by **not naming** this variable?
This would be easier to understand, less verbose, and also prevent don't-care variable names from accidentally overlapping.

I tried writing just `?` but a syntax error appears.

Comment: `SELECT ?item ?desiredVariable WHERE…` will leave out all other `?undesiredVariables` from the `WHERE` in the result.  (Do you need to use `SELECT *`?)

Comment: @TallTed: I never use `SELECT *`. My concern is about the code *after* the SELECT.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a SPARQL query, blank nodes in the query act in the role of "don't care" variables and they then don't show up in "SELECT *"

```
?item wdt:P582 [] .
```